# Rename files using Regex on Mac Terminal

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename files in a folder which has files with a name like:

> ['A_LOT_OF_TEXT'].pdf&blobcol=urldata&blobtable=MungoBlobs

- I basically want to obtain everything before the '.pdf' including the '.pdf'

After install brew rename, I tried using this but it does not work:

```
rename -n -v  '.*?(.pdf)' *
```

I get the error:

```
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.28'; .*?(.pdf) }
syntax error at (eval 2) line 1, near "; ."
```

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You certainly want

```sh
rename -n -v  's/^(.*?\.pdf).*/$1/' *
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/tlMWMq/1). Remove `-n` once you are sure the expression works for you well.

**EXPLANATION**

```sh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to $1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    pdf                      'pdf'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of $1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: you can combine your flags, for example you can just say `rename -nv  's/^(.*?\.pdf).*/$1/' *` to test and then rename `rename -v  's/^(.*?\.pdf).*/$1/' *` to execute

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to look at the example usage in the manpage for rename.
One possible solution is as follows:

```
rename -v -n 's/(.*pdf).*/$1/' *
```

### Explanation:

`-v`: print names of files successfully renamed
`-n`: dry run; don't actually rename
`$1`: First group in the matched regex
`*`: Run on all files in directory

Read more about the substitute command [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#:%7E:text=The%20syntax%20of%20the%20s,matched%20is%20replaced%20with%20replacement%20.).